# Name for a method that has only side effects

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic, methods

So, a method that alters its object is a *mutator*. A method that does not alter its object but returns a value (or reference to a value) is a *getter*. Is there a widely used name for a method that does not alter its object, does not return a value, but potentially alters objects passed to it as arguments. That is, a method that would only every be called for its side-effects on the arguments.

These methods are quite common if you are keen on the [Strategy design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685826/will-the-real-strategy-design-pattern-please-stand-up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an widely used name for a method that does not alter its object, does not return a value, but potentially alters objects passed to it as arguments.

The lack of replies suggests that, no, there is no *widely used* name for such a method.

Answer (score 1):

I call these methods *operations*.

They enable the object to be used as an *operator*. I don't call them *operators* however, because I program much C++, where `operator` method has a particular and different meaning.