# Different type of methods in OOP

Tags: java

I understand there are Mutator(to set), Accesor(to get) and Construtor(to initialize) methods in OOP.

But what is the method called that does things, such as "moveCharacterUpward()", "checkIfHitsWall();"? Are they called Operation methods?

Comment: All methods do something.  I'm not sure if there's a specific name for your examples.

Comment: moveCharacterUpward() <-- This is not a mutator, accesor nor construtor. What kind of method is this?

Comment: Does the method `moveCharacterUpwards` alter the state of the object it is a method of? If so, it is a mutator. Not all mutators are setters.

Comment: This question is unclear. It might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769816/name-for-a-method-that-has-only-side-effects

Comment: This question is unclear and yet there are people here who were able to answer my question, and I've accepted an answer. Don't make a fool of yourself, you're the only one here don't understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what is the method called that does things

Usually they're called *behavioral* methods - they define what Object(s) is/are able to do - it's behaviour. It really doesn't matter what kind of method is - same as others.

Generally if operation returns void (nothing) it's usually called method. When it returns something, it's called function.

**Note:** Generally, both are still methods. It's only way how to "mark" them or how to differentiate / name them.

Comment: Functions are also methods.

Comment: @BenAaronson Yes, but we can named it specifically as "function". Generally, both are methods. Someone can name it as i mentioned.

Comment: When I google "type of methods", all I can find is mutator, accesor, and constructor, but did not really mention anything else other than those. Just tried to google "behavioral methods", but could not really find anything. What keyword should I search instead?

Comment: @user3589718 Generally both are methods. Name "behavioral" is derived from the fact that method determines behaviour of Object - how i said, what Object is able to do through method. This is reason why they can be named as "behavioral" - it's only convention often used by many developers or you want to "name them" and try to differentiate them.

Comment: Well in Java, they are only called methods. I don't think it has got anything to do with `return value`. Rather generally `method` is for an object (instance of the class).

Comment: "When it returns something, it's called function" -> Does this mean it's a method but also can be called as a function?

Comment: @user3589718 yes, you are right. How i said - it's convetional and only way how to name them.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no word for what you want. And if you want to know why, you need look no further than the wording your question. You want to know what the name of a method that "does things" is. But what does it mean to "do something"? Mutators, accessors and constructors all do things, don't they?

Consider the following:

```
public void moveCharacterUpward(int distance)
{
    characterPosition.Y += distance;
}

public bool checkIfHitsWall(Movement movement)
{
    return movementResolver.CheckForCollision(characterPosition, wallPosition, movement);
}
```

(These are just made up examples, assuming `characterPosition`, `movementResolver` and `wallPosition` are private members of some type).

These were your two examples, but you'll see what they do is completely different. `moveCharacterUpward` essentially acts more like a combination of accessor and mutator, used in a specific way getting then setting a variable. Whereas `checkifHitsWall` doesn't change state at all, instead it answers a question for the code calling it. There's no term more specific than "method" covering both of these because they're conceptually not very similar!